# Retrieving MySQL BLOB field with Ruby/Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I make this simple MySQL query using `ActiveRecord::Base`

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM schedules WHERE id = 1"
schedule = (ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows sql)[0]
```

It happens that schedule[9] is `BLOB` data, but it gets retrieved as a ruby `String` object. Is that normal? How are `BLOB` objects represented in ruby? Coming from the Objective-C world, `BLOB` data is usually represented by `NSData` objects. Is there some kind of equivalent in Ruby?

Comment: What does schedule.class show? String perhaps?

Comment: @thisfeller `schedule` is an `Array` object

Comment: If you can, use `p schedule` and visually inspect the array. An array of bytes, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in ruby are just a sequence of arbitrary bytes - there is no separate data type.

Strings can be given an encoding which tells ruby to interpret the bytes as utf-8, utf-16, ISO-latin etc. when doing various operations on them but there's also the ASCII-8bit encoding (bit of a misnomer) which just means arbitrary bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't a serialized record in your model than a Blob is nothing other than a string which doesn't have size constraints. Strings are the base "data" object in Ruby.